In VFR, what is the list for "why to look outside"?
It is obvious we must mainly look outside during VFR. But what is the (somewhat) complete list of why?
 
Short term:

keep wings flat (roll)
keep altitude (pitch)
collision avoidance (planes, birds, close obstacles)
keep heading (yaw)
close weather (avoiding close clouds)
what else?

 
Medium term:

check if we are at the expected place (points of reference)
collision avoidance (ground)
weather (distant conditions)
spot where to do an emergency landing
enjoy the view
what else?

 
Other :

it's the law (*1)

 

Edit:

(*1) from a comment from Jamiec


I'd say you've got the list pretty much covered...

All I would have added was "Because you're legally obliged to", but that's just a restating of some of your existing ones (cloud avoidance, collision avoidance)

Because that's where the accident is.
